# Crowbar circuit with TL431 help

Tags: voltage, protection, triac, tl431

So I'm trying to create a OVP using TL431 an a triac, i have checked the datasheet but since i suck at math i don't really get how to set the ref voltage..

datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431b-q1.pdf

My example circuit: [image]

I'm having a 19v power supply, and i want to make it so that if the supply for some reason should reach over 20v, it blows the fuse.. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Why a triac and not an scr?

Comment: what do you mean with scr? well i just googled it, i thought both where the same thing haha.. Still new at this. Have to look in the junkbox and see if i have one.

Comment: silicon controlled rectifier.

Comment: Also, I've no idea why you wired up the TL431 that way, with 19 V across it. Might be interesting to try that ... once.

Comment: I was not going to use that, I'm just trying to simulate different things to see if i got to understand how it works/how to set the ref voltage.

Comment: is it possible to use a triac instead of scr for ovp? I can't find any scr in my junkbox so..

Comment: I suppose you might try, putting a diode in series with the gate. So it appears you really need a full design done, given what I see in that circuit. The TL431 doesn't work that way, for example. It's a great device, though. And it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might work, but try flipping the triac so MT2 is grounded and MT1 connects to the input voltage, and connect the 'cathode' of the TL431 ONLY to the gate.

Calculate the gate resistors as @Tony suggests, so for about 19.5V you could use 2.49K and 16.9K, standard E48 values.

This circuit won't work with an SCR because SCRs don't generally come in the opposite polarity.

---

Edit: Like the below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fioYeW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the voltage at the REF input of the TL431 exceeds ~2.5V the gate current increases until the triac triggers and shorts out the supply, blowing the fuse. The triac is operated  in quadrant III (gate and MT2 both negative wrt MT1), which is always acceptable. Below the trigger voltage the TL431 conducts < 1mA which should not trigger most triacs. If it is a problem (or just to be sure), you can connect a 100 ohm resistor from MT1 to gate.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain a little more on how you meant? i tried to do it but it just wouldn't work so i prolly did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried it but the fuse just won't blow.. Not sure if it is the simulation that is wrong (using multisim)

https://i.gyazo.com/c44b50921f5268a162a07672544b9da8.png

Comment: Measure the gate current in your simulation. It should be more than 100mA, so the triac should be triggering. Measure the fuse current- maybe it is not modeled and the triac is actually on in the simulation.

Comment: The current won't go through the triac only the tl431..
https://i.gyazo.com/4d383d4016ffff9ce7b8bf8ab67aa368.png

Comment: Sounds like your triac model is missing or broken.

Comment: Hmm I've tried 5 different models of triacs, same problem.. so weird

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/691f98f9c17c2239f4b7bb8d80b0268d.png

I even trie this: https://i.gyazo.com/ee21a85050c6652897b2241ba6b6f630.png
So i guess you're right.. something with the model

Comment: Well- if  the triac was flipped (MT1/MT2 reversed) that would do it.

Comment: Tried flipping it, same issue. Going to try this on a breadboard instead.
Do you know of any calculator to get the desired ovp? For example if i have 12v input and want the triac to activate at 14v. What values would i need for the resistors?

Comment: Use @Tony's calculations.. If R2 is 2.49K then R1 ~= (Vtrig-2.5V) K

Comment: Oh forgot that. Thanks you so much for all the help, all of you!

Comment: One more thing, i downloaded a custom triac model which is working perfectly with your circuit. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- Two transistors back-back= 1 SCR
- two SCR's back-back= 1 Triac
- Since hFE & power rating of transistors have a wide range Vgt threshold is affected by Vbe bulk resistance and Vce(sat) so the gate threshold voltage is not very accurate for low voltage OVP.

Vgt's can range from 650mV to 5V in datasheets but you can roll your own if you want.  The device must not FUSE before the "fuse" according to SOA and fuse times.

- There are better ways than using Vgt , instead, use a precision comparator to drive it.
- FYI on TL431 is like using Non-Inverting Op Amp gain on 2.5V reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explination, Going to try the comparator method a bit later!

Comment: yer welcome, ensure comparator has a  bit of LPF so that tiny glitches do not false trigger OVP, ie. make a spec for OVP duration and threshold.